# Product of real quadratic roots

Tags: quadratics

If product of roots '$p$' of equation $x^2 – 2ax + 8 – a = 0$ lies between its roots, then maximum
integral value of '$p$' is _____

My approach is as follow

$f\left( x \right) = {x^2} - 2ax + 8 - a$

${D^2} = 4{a^2} - 4\left( {8 - a} \right) \ge 0 \Rightarrow {a^2} + a - 8 \ge 0$

${a^2} + a - 8 \ge 0 \Rightarrow a \in \left( { - \infty ,\frac{{ - 1 - \sqrt {33} }}{2}} \right) \cup \left( {\frac{{ - 1 + \sqrt {33} }}{2},\infty } \right)$

$\alpha  + \beta  = 2a$ & $\alpha \beta  = 8 - a$

$\alpha \beta  \in \left( {\alpha ,\beta } \right)$ where $\beta  > \alpha $

How do we proceed from hered

Comment: What do you mean by "lie between the roots"?

Comment: @martycohen presumably $r_1\leq r_1r_2 \leq r_2$ for roots $r_1,r_2$

Comment: Thanks. I somehow ignored the "product of".

Answer (score 2):

The roots are

$$a\pm \sqrt{a^2-(8-a)}$$

and the product of the roots is $8-a$, so defining $p=8-a$, we wish to maximize $p$ (among integers) subject to constraints

$$ 8-p-\sqrt{(8-p)^2-p}\leq p\leq 8-p+ \sqrt{(8-p)^2-p}.$$

A quick sketch shows optimally the upper constraint must bind so

$$p= 8-p+ \sqrt{(8-p)^2-p}\implies p=5.$$

[image]

Comment: won't it be $2a\pm \sqrt{4a^2-(8-a)}$?

Comment: @DeBARtha No. divide by 2. also check your discriminant

Comment: oh yes, I see it...